# Error processing reputation sum

Tags: bug, status-completed, reputation

I'm not sure this is right place to report a bug, but here we go:

https://stackoverflow.com/users/recent/113794?Tab=Reputation&StartDate=2009-10-20&EndDate=2009-10-20

[155 pts http://img269.imageshack.us/img269/9632/155pts.jpg](http://img269.imageshack.us/img269/9632/155pts.jpg)

Why some yesterday up votes wasn't counted?

Comment: This is the right place to report bugs and support questions.

Answer (score 3):

155 agrees with what [my reputation tracker](http://csharpindepth.com/StackOverflow/ReputationTracker.aspx?so=113794&sf=&su=&meta=&mode=yesterday&showflair=true) thinks you should have got.

If it's just upvotes which didn't contribute to reputation, I'd normally think of Community Wiki posts, but from the screenshot it looks like you got 3 votes for [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1595118/1595167#1595167) but only 10 rep.

I've seen this happen before if you hit the rep cap but then have some reputation subtracted when fraudulent votes are removed... it gives you an effective rep cap lower than 200. You may or may not get some of that reputation back if you ask for a reputation recalc.

Comment: Hi Jon, ty for your answer and interesting C# application; as far as I can tell, none can be counted as "fraudulent" but I prefer SO-ops tell that;

Comment: The fraudulent votes would already have been removed - the situation would be that you'd reach the rep cap, then have more (legit) votes cast, then some "bad" votes would be removed - but you'd end up with a "low" rep cap for that day. That's what's happened to me sometimes.

Comment: do you still count rep, Jon? =D

Comment: @Rubens: I'm still interested in my count per day - less so my overall total.

Answer (score 1):

We can't see your "recent" tab, as it is not public. One can only see his or her own. But as a wild guess: did you hit the 200 points daily reputation cap? Look for it by searching "[reputation] cap" here in meta for some explanation.

Comment: sorry, Ralph, I didnt knew its private; I'm aware 200 rep cap, but I just made 155; I'll update my post with a sccreenshot

Comment: I just detected a case too. One of my answers was accepted on Sep 21, and this were the only rep popints I earned that day. It does show the acc, but not the 15 points, and does not count them either.

Comment: All aboard the fail boat =)

Answer (score 0):

When this happens your reputation will now be properly adjusted (whatever the cause: vote fraud, reversed votes, deleted users, etc.).  This is part of [a larger set of reputation changes](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/123319/upcoming-reputation-history-changes) aimed at keeping reputation current/in sync at all times.